# How to create a "C single-line comment" macro

Tags: c, gcc, macros, c-preprocessor

I am trying to create a "single line comment" macro in **C**, this is used conditionally to comment out lines of codes, according to some global macro definitions. It is the same idea expressed in [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cc-tip-5-a-cc-comment-macro/184401344).

Trying many permutations of this code, I keep getting error messages from the compiler.

For example, directly following the code sample from that page:

```
#define COMMENT SLASH(/)
#define SLASH(s) /##s
#define DEBUG_ONLY COMMENT
DEBUG_ONLY a = b;   // <-- line #83
```

GCC gives the following error:

> prog.c:83:1: error: pasting "/" and "/" does not give a valid preprocessing token
>       prog.c:83: error: expected expression before ‘/’ token

As mentioned, I played with that theme and tried many variations but all fail giving similar diagnostics.

What am I doing wrong, and why doesn't the code from the article compiles well?

Comment: The compiler is telling you what you're doing wrong. These tricks sometimes work with broken compilers, but they shouldn't work at all and you shouldn't use them.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze - are you saying that this code is basically illegal? Why would it be so? Why can't I create a comment macro?

Comment: Yep, illegal. Steve's answer mentions the relevant part of the standard.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It doesn't work because the language specification doesn't allow it. In effect, comment removal happens *before* macro replacement. Once comments have been removed, `//` is not a valid token (like the error message says). It can't be generated by macro replacement, and it no longer means "comment".

This is "Translation phases" in the standard. The section numbering differs, but all of C89, C99 and C11 define in phase 3:

> Each comment is replaced by one space character.

and then in phase 4:

> macro invocations are expanded

Comment: I am not sure I understand. "comment removal happens before macro replacement" - so at lease the `DEBUG_ONLY` macro should become an empty macro, shouldn't it (I mean, the comment is now removed)?

Comment: @ysap: no. The only comment in your code is `// <-- line #83`, which is removed in phase 3. In phase 4, `DEBUG_ONLY` attempts to use token pasting to create an invalid token, `//`. Therefore the program is ill-formed.

Comment: OK, then, so is there no way to generate a "comment" macro in a conforming compiler?

Comment: That sucks... Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 10):

A debug macro:

```
#define DEBUG(x) x
```

Which can be turned off in production as:

```
#define DEBUG(x)
```

Or IIRC `#undef` (sorry, my C is rusty).

Comment: Tanks. The question is a simplification of the situation. The actual code is more complex, so I cannot use this style.

Comment: @ysap If so, could you post some code that shows why you can't use this style?

Comment: @FUZxxl - I am basically trying to superimpose that functionality on an existing code construct, in which the macro is just a test and the actual code follows it. What I want to do is to completely comment out the code that follows, without changing the whole body of code (replacing that macro everywhere). Also, the conditional following code contains function calls by itself, so their parameter lists will not be processed by the preprocessor very well, I think.

Comment: @ysap I can't really understand what you try to do. Would you mind giving some code? CPP is not so dumb when it comes to parameter lists.

Comment: @FUZxxl - let's say that I have in my existing code `#define d(x) if (x>2)`, and have a lot of statements like the following in many files: `d(3) { printf("%f\n", sinf(u)); }`. I want to comment out that statement block w/o rewriting the code. If I could add the `//` string to the `d(x)` it will do the work effortlessly.

Comment: You could also do DEBUG(d(3) { printf("%f\n", sinf(u)); }), you know.

Comment: @FUZxxl - yes, I can do many other things - but the thing is that I don't want to change the existing code!

Comment: @ysap The way that applies the least changes to the code is what [Joachim Pileborg](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15545577/417501) suggested. I don't see how what you want to do affects the code more or less than what I say.

Comment: @ysap, just do `#define d(x) if((x > 0) && 0)`, any (halfway) smart compiler will just get rid of the whole `d(something) { ... }` constructs.

Comment: Thanks, @vonbrand. The first constructive comment in this discussion. This certainly makes sense, assuming optimization is activated.

Answer (score 7):

Why not simply just use e.g.

```
#ifdef DEBUG
a = b;
#endif  /* DEBUG */
```

Less trouble, and just as readable.

Comment: When it appears in a few places, you may be right. When it appears in dozens of dozens of places across many modules, with deep nesting levels, this will certainly make your code unreadable.

Comment: @ysap Perhaps that is the reason why you shouldn't keep trashy debug code all over the project in the first place? Nobody stops you from copying a certain piece of code to a separate test project.

Comment: @Lundin - nobody, except that the test are in a certain context that may involve a lot of preliminary operations in certain scenarios, which means that your test cases become convoluted themselves.

Comment: @ysap the problem here is that your code is already unreadable and unmaintainable.  You need an actual logging framework, not more macros.

Comment: @djechlin - thanks for the code review. This is appreciated, especially w/o even *seeing* the code...

Comment: @ysap there are signs.  C++ is a language that lets you deprecate use of macros entirely.  When you have a problem you can't solve without macros, then there is something wrong with your code.  Furthermore you already said "it appears in dozens and dozens of places."  Sounds very not DRY, hence unmaintainable.  Move common code to a function, don't dummy out common code with a macro.  See Scott Meyers Effective C++, Item 2.  And why are you trying to write your own logging framework in the preprocessor?  Stop reinventing the wheel.  Just research and use a logging framework.

Comment: Note: Yes, there are exceptions to my broad sweeping macro-related claim.  I am aware of them.  This is not one of them.

Comment: @djechlin - if only you looked carefully, you'd see that the question is about C and not C++. Thanks anyway for the insight.

Comment: @djechlin - to be clear, I agree that there may be other ways to solve the problem - some may even be preferable - but in this case it is an *evolution* of existing code that started small and grew up in scale. All done in a fast pace for tight schedule, so I am trying to avoid refactoring as much as possible if not necessary.

Comment: @ysap code doesn't evolve, it rots.  Throw it out and start over.  If your management believes that evolving up a prototype lets them hit more aggressive targets, then find new management, as they are wrong.

Answer (score 1):

With a `#define` macro, you can't comment out an entire line *per se*, but you can comment out everything up to the next semi-colon. I find that this method works pretty well.

```
#define LOG_LVL 111100011
//              987654321
#if(LOG_LVL%10   >= 1  )
    #define LOG1 if(1)
#else
    #define LOG1 if(0)
#endif//End LOG1 if-block

#if(LOG_LVL%1000 >= 100)
    #define LOG3 if(1)
#else
    #define LOG3 if(0)
#endif//End LOG3 if-block
```

As long as you are careful with your semicolons, this should work fine. By default a non-braced `if` statement will only execute the following line.

The other benefit of doing logging like this is that you can fine tune what level of logging you want. In this example `LOG1` is enabled and `LOG3` is disabled. If i wanted my logging to be more verbose, i can quickly change `LOG_LVL 111100011` to have a `1` (or higher) in it's **3** digit so that `LOG3` will be enabled.

Answer (score 1):

I used `#define cout(x) //cout<<x;` for my applications. You may want to modify it like

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define cout(x) cout<<x;
#else
#define cout(x)
```

And use it as

```
cout(arg0<<arg1<<arg2);
```

Here, you won't be commenting the line and thus won't need separate line for avoiding print.
Further you can use cout wherever printing has to be done unconditionally.

```
cout("Print this when debugging");
cout<<"Always print this";
```

Comment: Thanks, and welcome to SO. Please note your answer (assuming it's working) only addresses the printout case. The question was more general in terms. It asks for the elimination of arbitrary statements by converting them to a comment. +1 for welcome, anyway.